# Jmeter Throws NoSuchMethodException, but the method does exist

Tags: java, junit, jmeter

Currently trying to use Junit to create some concurrency tests to run in Jmeter

My current project Structure looks like this [image]

From RasterTest.java, I'm trying to call a method in CommonMethods.java and a method in SetUp.java. 
When I run this as a JUnit Test in eclipse, the methods in CommonMethods and SetUp are called and everything works fine. When I export this to a JAR and run the same in Jmeter, I get an error given below (getProperty is a method inside SetUp )

`Trace -- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: utils.SetUp.getProperty`

I couldn't find any resources, hence i thought this maybe due to the methods being static, but i tried accessing the method by creating an object too. That Didn't help, got the same error.

Attaching the class CommonMethods for reference :

```
public class CommonMethods {

    public String getProperty (String key) {
             // Some code
    }

    public void setUrl() {

        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

}
```

Calling it as :

```
CommonMethods cm = new CommonMethods();
System.out.println(cm.getProperty("URL"));
cm.setUrl();
```

I don't understand why Jmeter throws this error and how do i get around it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using jpgc-perfmon-2.1. If not zip that into jmeter and then  remove plugin cmn jar file from lib and update jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter.jar file with the latest version.

Seems like its kind of configuration issue.

Comment: I unzipped all the JARs in jpgc-perfmon-2.1 into lib. Also added jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.6.jar which seems to be the latest version. Still not working. Any other ideas that i can try out? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its a version incompatibility issue of jmeter and Perfmon plugin most probably. Hence, please download an older version of Jmeter and giva it a try.